# JSF & Primefaces - RemoteCommand not working properly

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to implement primefaces' RemoteCommand tag to my application, but somehow it doesn't work as the docs say.

**What I'm trying to implement:** I have a several pages with different layouts, but all are using the same JSF Template. (Basically the content of the template changes). The different pages should load automatically though, one after another, one by one, with an interval between one another.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remoteSwitchPage" actionListener="#{circuitBean.redirect()}" autoRun="false"/>
```

This is my JSF code, which `should` supply me with a JavaScript method called `remoteSwitchPage()`, but it **does not!** It should also `not` run, because I've said `autoRun="false"`, but it **runs on load!** After calling the method `remoteSwitchPage()` it should render another page via Java (This one works actually. Somehow JSF wouldn't find the redirect method when leaving the brackets, that's why I've put them).

So summarized:

1. JavaScript does not supply me with the `remoteSwitchPage()`
2. The remoteCommand runs on page load, which it `should not!`
3. JSF won't find my ManagedBean method `resize()`, when leaving the brackets

Do you guys got any clue what I am doing wrong here?

I'm using `primefaces 4.0` and `JSF 2.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Managed it as said in the comment of Simegos' Post.

I created a hidden button that would be clicked every X seconds by JavaScript. Every page that becomes rendered after the button got clicked, needs to implement the following code. It would be ideal to put the code in a template which all rendered pages will implement.

```
<h:form id="form" class="hidden"> --> Hidden button
    <h:commandButton id="switchPageButton" action="#{circuitBean.renderNextScreen()}"/>
</h:form>    
<h:outputScript>
    $(function() {
        $(".hidden").each(function() { --> Declare Form as hidden, since it becomes overwritten by JSF
            $(this).css("display","none");
        });
        var switchPageLink = $("#form\\:switchPageButton"); --> Get Button via ID
        window.setInterval(function() {
            switchPageLink.click(); --> Click it 
        }, #{circuitBean.pageInterval}); --> after X seconds. I'm reading the interval through the bean here. You can just put a number in there
    });
</h:outputScript>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remoteSwitchPage" actionListener="#{circuitBean.redirect}" />
```

JSF will try to find `getRedirect`, that's why you should use the `circuitBean.redirect()`.

**EDIT**: i think you should use `action` instead of `actionListener`.

Here is my example code (tested):

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="logoutAccount()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
```

**Another part of HTML (end of the page):**

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:remoteCommand action="#{sessionMB.logout()}" name="logoutAccount" />
</h:form>
```

**Bean:**

```
public void logout() {
    account = null;
    logged = false;
    FacesUtil.addInfoGrowl(MessageProvider.getMessage("message.logout.success"), null);
    FacesUtil.redirectToPage("", true);
}
```

**redirectToPage method:**

```
public static boolean redirectToPage(String completePath, Boolean keepMessages) {
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(keepMessages);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(SimegoUtil.redirectProject() + completePath);

        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        FacesUtil.addErrorGrowl(MessageProvider.getMessage("message.redirectFail"), null);
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, will be like this:
Click **>** call remoteCommand Javascript **>** call bean **>** redirect to another page

I just didn't get the template part you said, if i can help in something more just tell me, hope you fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. Is it possible to call `logoutAccount()` programatically, after X seconds, without needing the user to click on it? **Edit:** See, this is why I wanted to use that method in plain JavaScript (<script>logoutAccount()</script>)

Comment: The only solution I could think of is creating an invisible button, which will be "pressed" via some JavaScript

Comment: setTimeout() on document load

Comment: For me, it worked the opposite: using actionListener="#circuitBean.redirect}". Using actionListener="#circuitBean.redirect()}" doesn't work: it seems it cann't find the method

Comment: i used only `action="#{bean.method()}"`, if you can paste your method it would help :)